# Do the same firebase bindings (.on() methods) multiple time

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Is it problematic in an app (ios/android using react native for example) or a website, to relaunch firebase bindings ?

this code for example :

```
var starCountRef = firebase.database().ref('posts/' + postId + '/starCount');
starCountRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {
  updateStarCount(postElement, snapshot.val());
});
```

If i happen to launch multiple time the binding function :

```
starCountRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {
  updateStarCount(postElement, snapshot.val());
});
```

Will it erase the previous one ? Or does it stack on top of another and i received the update from firebase in case the object change multiple time ?

Thanks in advance to the community

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have two listeners at one location, the data will not be duplicated in terms of network traffic.  Both listeners will share the same incoming snapshots from the database.

Comment: ok and if i have 100 listeners that can be a problem or ?

Comment: As long as you have enough memory to hold those listener objects, which are probably not very large at all.